# What is the return value of this conditional (groovy script)

Tags: if-statement, groovy, return-value

What will be the return value of this `if/else` statement?

```
if (salary <= 3000) {
  return discount < 0.40
}
else {
  return discount < 0.60
}
```

I'm not sure if the return value of each `if` and `else` will be a `boolean` or `0.40` and `0.60`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a boolean. The `<`, `>`, `!=`, `>=`, `==`, `<=` expressions will evaluate to a boolean value:

```
def mustDiscount(salary, discount = 0.5) {
    if (salary <= 3000) {
      return discount < 0.40
    }
    else {
      return discount < 0.60
    }
}

mustDiscount(2000).with {
    assert it in Boolean
    assert !it
}


mustDiscount(4000).with {
    assert it in Boolean
    assert it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type for that would be a boolean (true or false), both in the if block and else block.

Also `return discount == 0.50` would return a boolean.